# Make a card dynamic with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this data in my **index.js** file:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.demos = [ {
    paragrafo: 'richiesta',
    title:'demo1',
    paragrafo2:'dskjdfdjfdfjkdf',
    link: 'https://www.google.it',
    },
    {
    paragrafo: 'richiesta',
    title:'demo2',
    paragrafo2:'dfhfhfjgfkjghfjkgf',
    link: 'https://www.youtube.it',
    },
    {
    paragrafo: 'richiesta',
    title:'demo3',
    paragrafo2:'sjdsdjddfjdf',
    link: 'https://www.sportmediaset.it',
    },
    {
    paragrafo: 'richiesta',
    title:'demo4',
    paragrafo2:'sdjkdhdkjfhdjfh',
    link: 'https://www.elbocon.pe',
    },
    ];
})
.component('card', {
 templateUrl: 'card.html'
 })
```

in my **card.html** component i used ng-repeat, i tried iterating it with ng -repeat:

```html
<div ng-repeat="demo in demos">
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>{{demo.paragrafo}}</p>
      <h5 class="card-title">{{demo.title}}</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
      <p class="card-text">{{demo.paragrafo2}}</p>
      <a class="card-link">{{demo.link}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in **index.html**, I put the component in the html index as well:

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <card></card>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

But it doesn't work, I would like 4 cards with different data to appear, can someone help me?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - could you elaborate? What is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [bind your data to the component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). Additionally, accessing that data inside the component requires a reference to $ctrl.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.demos = [{
        paragrafo: 'richiesta',
        title: 'demo1',
        paragrafo2: 'dskjdfdjfdfjkdf',
        link: 'https://www.google.it',
      },
      {
        paragrafo: 'richiesta',
        title: 'demo2',
        paragrafo2: 'dfhfhfjgfkjghfjkgf',
        link: 'https://www.youtube.it',
      },
      {
        paragrafo: 'richiesta',
        title: 'demo3',
        paragrafo2: 'sjdsdjddfjdf',
        link: 'https://www.sportmediaset.it',
      },
      {
        paragrafo: 'richiesta',
        title: 'demo4',
        paragrafo2: 'sdjkdhdkjfhdjfh',
        link: 'https://www.elbocon.pe',
      },
    ];
  }])
  .component('card', {
    bindings: {
      demo: '<'
    },
    template: '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem"><div class="card-body"><p>{{$ctrl.demo.paragrafo}}</p><h5 class="card-title">{{$ctrl.demo.title}}</h5><h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6><p class="card-text">{{$ctrl.demo.paragrafo2}}</p><a class="card-link">{{$ctrl.demo.link}}</a></div></div>'
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <card demo="data" ng-repeat="data in demos">
  </card>
</div>
```